# How do I stop ActiveRecord localising the time? in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, rails-activerecord

I have an application that allows organisations to manage holiday requests. When a person makes a request for holiday from 1 January to 2 January, the to and from attributes are stored in the DB as DateTime objects.  The from would have a time of midnight on the 1 January and the to would have a time of 23:59:59.

I have an account that is based in Warsaw, which I understand to be GMT-1.  Now when their record is stored it would be stored as from 31 December at 11pm to 2 January at 11pm.  This causes all manner of problems, most notably the app thinks 3 days are used for the holiday.

How can I stop this happening?

Thanks

Robin

Comment: The first check I would do is whether javascript in the frontend is using strings or date objects to display the FROM and TO values. Keep in mind that Javascript when creating Date objects converts dates to local timezone.

Once the communication with javascript is ruled out, I would check whether the server time zone is causing any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

By convention , Rails stores the DateTime objects in UTC in the database . The most proper way to manage the timezone is `config.time_zone` in your `config/application.rb` . There is a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?view=asciicast) about TimeZones , which would be useful in your case.